# Program (source provided) takes twice as long to run on Ivy Bridge Xeon than older mobile Sandy Bridge

Tags: linux, macos, performance, x86-64

I have two computers on which I'm trying to run the same program.  Although the program should run at least a little faster on system B, it's actually twice as fast (or better) on system A.  This makes no sense to me, and I'd really love if anyone could help me figure out what in the world is causing this odd performance problem.  I added a third system as a sanity check, and now I'm even more baffled.

System A:

- 2011 MacBook Pro with Sandy Bridge CPU
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2820QM CPU @ 2.30GHz
- Intel power meter reports it running at 3.1GHz while running the program
- Compiler is clang++:  Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)

System B:

- 2-sockets, 12 cores/socket Ivy Bridge Xeon server bought in 2013
- Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v2 @ 2.70GHz
- turbostat reports one core running at 3.5GHz while running the program
- Compiler is clang++:  Ubuntu clang version 3.5-1ubuntu1 (trunk) (based on LLVM 3.5)

System C:

- Quad-core Haswell Core i5
- Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4430 CPU @ 3.00GHz
- turbostat reports that cores max out at 3.2GHz
- Compiler is clang++:  clang version 3.5.1 (tags/RELEASE_351/final)

You can find the source code to the program at:  http://www.cs.binghamton.edu/~millerti/test.tgz

The compiler command lines I use on both systems are as follows:

- Scalar version:  `clang++ -O3 -msse3 x.c 3_22_1b.c`
- Vector version:  `clang++ -O3 -msse3 x.c 3_22_1.c`

There are two rather odd things about this.  One is that the scalar versions are slightly faster than the vector versions.  But the really **huge** problem is that this program takes more than twice as long to run on the server (system B) than on the notebook (system A).

On System A:

```
$ time ./a.out
real    0m22.908s
user    0m22.853s
sys 0m0.038s
```

On System B:

```
$ time ./a.out
real    0m55.354s
user    0m55.310s
sys     0m0.000s
```

On System C:

```
$ time ./a.out
real    0m42.421s
user    0m42.400s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Other facts:

- Sandy Bridge and Ivy Bridge have the same amount of L1 cache (64KB total).  Actually, so does the Haswell.
- System B has way more L2 cache than any of the others
- The executables are very small and should at least mostly fit into the L1I cache
- The amount of data is 176 floats, so the L1D cache hit rate should be about 100%
- IVB and SB microarchitectures are very similar, and the differences are mostly in favor of the IVB
- All systems are being run otherwise unloaded.  The notebook (System A) does have a minimum of other stuff going on.  The server (System B) and the Haswell (System C) are completely unloaded.  No other users or anything.
- `top` shows the programs getting 100% CPU in all systems.  `iotop` shows no I/O going on during that time on the server.
- Using g++ doesn't make much difference compared to clang in any case.
- For reference I added the Haswell, and it's not illuminating anything.  It makes no sense that that would be a whole lot faster than the Ivy Bridge but slower than the Sandy Bridge.
- There's no way the operating system is going to have any impact here, and there's no way Apple's done some kind of magic in their LLVM compiler that they haven't shared that can make the program that much faster.
- I did try just benchmarking tanh.  It turns out that it's about twice as fast on MacOS X than Linux.  100 million invocations of tanh takes 1.484s on System A (Mac), while it takes 3.380s on System C (Haswell) and 3.392s on System B (IVB server).  However, I have done profiling, and tanh accounts for only about 35% of the total runtime, so it can't explain the whole performance disparity.
- `-ffast-math` doesn't help.
- I'm in the process of installing Linux in a VM on the Mac.  I'll run the same code on Linux on the Mac to see how much is glibc's slow math and how much is the CPU.  (Since this is compute-intensive, the virtualization won't matter.)  I'll add the results later.

Comment: I ran this from within an Ubuntu VM on the Mac.  It took about 65 seconds.  However, Parallels doesn't get along well with Ubuntu 14.10, so this isn't terribly informative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause turned out to be entirely `tanh`.  This wasn't revealed by profiling because of profiling overhead.  I don't know why I didn't think of this last night, but this morning, I commented out the tanh, and here's what I get:

System A:

```
$ time ./a.out
real    0m4.443s
user    0m4.433s
sys 0m0.008s
```

System B:

```
$ time ./a.out
real    0m3.373s
user    0m3.368s
sys     0m0.003s
```

System C:

```
$ time ./a.out
real    0m4.054s
user    0m4.050s
sys     0m0.000s
```

Those numbers all make sense.  So the conclusion is that the Linux implementation of tanh is really lousy.  I'll have to implement my own or snag the tanh source from the BSD libc.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the results with: `-march=` options. Ideally, you would build `libc` and `libm` this way.

Comment: Not much difference.  I added -march=native on all systems.  On System A (mac), it's 22.4s.  On System B (ivb), it's 54.4s.  On System C (haswell), it's 41.9s.  The conclusions are that Haswell has some architectural advantages over IVB, but Linux's tanh sucks, so the Mac is faster.  And contrary to what the profiling said, tanh totally dominates the run time.

Comment: Google came up with some hits on glibc math performance. https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8828936.  Apparently glibc is slow because of making sure everything is rounded perfectly.  I just single-stepped through the `tanh` code, and it moves the float to an int register, and does a lot of compares and bit-tests.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check assembly listing. One compiler might generate SISD instructions and the other SIMD - like mulss xmm0, xmm7 instead of mulps xmm0, xmm7 that can be four times faster (at the same CPU GHz). Then there are AVX instructions to try.

The problem that you describe is usually caused by the slowest being produced by an older compiler or, in my case, using the latest free Microsoft compiler versus the latest GCC for Linux, where the latter produced the superior implementations.